# How to IndexedDB in webworkers in FirefoxOS 1.X

Tags: indexeddb, web-worker, firefox-os

I know that IDB and web workers was just implemented this year, but reading the mdn[1] says this join works in b2g (firefoxOS) since first release.

I'm doing an app using idb in a worker but fails to start in 1.X versions of b2g.
I'm already look for some moz-idb(ish) variable in the self but found nothing (this one is really hard without a console or a proper debuger :( ), also search deeply in the mdn and still no example or documentation of idb in worker in b2g.

can you help-me with a simple example or variable name of the indexeddb?

Sources: 
[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAUyb.png

Comment: What the hell is b2g?

Comment: IDB on workers is not available in 1.x versions of b2g.  It was only recently added to the worker context.

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDB was added to workers in Firefox 37:

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/37.0/releasenotes/

Firefox OS 2.2 is based on this same release.  All earlier versions of Firefox OS will be missing IDB on workers.

Note, it should be possible to feature detect IDB in workers and use a polyfill if its not available.  It basically involves proxying operations back to the main window using postMessage().

Comment: It was not. See the test case here: https://jsfiddle.net/fuj7koog/ Please verify your claims before posting answers or closing bug reports.

Comment: I agree that the jsfiddle does not work on older FF versions (although it does work in FF43+).  That appears to be a sandbox iframe problem, though, and not related to IDB in workers.  Use this site instead: http://mozilla.pettay.fi/workerconsole/

Comment: Yeah sure, jsFiddle somehow hacks workers so that they don't work - I guess this is what are you trying to say. I think this only changes the situation to the one where feature sometimes works, sometimes does not. Daniel Fox sure did check his browser version and yet posted this question, which means it didn't work for him either.

Comment: I dug a bit more and we actually blocked IDB in sandbox iframes completely until FF 42.  We then propagated that change to workers in FF 43.  See: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1176434 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1184973

Comment: I couldn't find any relevant info to "disabling IDB in iframes" in neither of those bug reports you linked. The former one is report filed by me by the way and contains no mention of that for sure. Unless this is a documented limitation it's a bug - either in documentation or code.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-pasted.  I fixed the link a few minutes ago.  For reference, its https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1176434

Answer (score -1):

Well I totally agree it's pretty hard to debug workers normally. But there are some tricks you can use, and I went with [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames). This was the result of calling the method on [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/self):

> [`Function`, `Object`, `eval`, `EventTarget`, `WorkerGlobalScope`, `DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope`, `postMessage`, `onmessage`, `FileReaderSync`, `Performance`, `URL`, `WorkerLocation`, `WorkerNavigator`, `XMLHttpRequestEventTarget`, `XMLHttpRequestUpload`, `XMLHttpRequest`, `Blob`, `BroadcastChannel`, `Cache`, `CacheStorage`, `DOMCursor`, `DOMError`, `Error`, `DOMException`, `DOMRequest`, `DOMStringList`, `Event`, `File`, `FormData`, `Headers`, **`IDBCursor`**, **`IDBCursorWithValue`**, **`IDBDatabase`**, **`IDBFactory`**, **`IDBIndex`**, **`IDBKeyRange`**, **`IDBObjectStore`**, **`IDBRequest`**, **`IDBOpenDBRequest`**, **`IDBTransaction`**, **`IDBVersionChangeEvent`**, `ImageBitmap`, `ImageData`, `MessageChannel`, `MessageEvent`, `MessagePort`, `Notification`, `PerformanceEntry`, `PerformanceMark`, `PerformanceMeasure`, `Promise`, `Request`, `Response`, `TextDecoder`, `TextEncoder`, `URLSearchParams`, `WebSocket`, `Worker`, `Console`, `undefined`, `Array`, `Boolean`, `JSON`, `Date`, `Math`, `isNaN`, `isFinite`, `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, `NaN`, `Infinity`, `Number`, `String`, `escape`, `unescape`, `uneval`, `decodeURI`, `encodeURI`, `decodeURIComponent`, `encodeURIComponent`, `RegExp`, `InternalError`, `EvalError`, `RangeError`, `ReferenceError`, `SyntaxError`, `TypeError`, `URIError`, `Iterator`, `StopIteration`, `ArrayBuffer`, `Int8Array`, `Uint8Array`, `Int16Array`, `Uint16Array`, `Int32Array`, `Uint32Array`, `Float32Array`, `Float64Array`, `Uint8ClampedArray`, `Proxy`, `WeakMap`, `Map`, `Set`, `DataView`, `Symbol`, `Intl`, `WeakSet`, `Reflect`]

As you can see, the IDB related objects (can't be instantiated using `new`) are present, but the instances are not. Also, the `IDBEnvironment` constructor is missing. Not the first thing that's wrong with workers in Firefox.

I created a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1228347) - here's a test for the feature: https://jsfiddle.net/fuj7koog/1/

Comment: Searching depper I only found the IDB variables start from b2g v2.2 (with the release simulators) and with this version works without problem.

Comment: BTW exists a workarround to that like dataApi in workers?

Comment: The indexedDB attributes does not show in getOwnPropertyNames() because self is a DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope that derives from WorkerGlobalScope (where the attribute is actually defined).  Also, IDBEnvironment is a [NoInterfaceObject] in the spec.  It does not have a constructor.

Comment: @BenKelly Good point, the IDB global objects can't be instantiated indeed. And `WorkerGlobalScope` didn't seem to contain IDB instance either.

Comment: `WorkerGlobalScope.prototype` is what will have an "indexedDB" property.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky But it's not accessible from `WorkerGlobalScope` instance (which is `self`).

Comment: I think the discussion with Ben Kelly above clears this up: indexedDB was disabled in sandboxed iframes (and workers started from them) in Firefox 42 and earlier, to prevent them from effectively setting cookies that interact with non-sandboxed iframes.  And jsfiddle runs its stuff in a sandboxed iframe.  That restriction is being lifted in Firefox 43.  The documentation definitely needs clarification here, though.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Yes, it was documentation issue - that was also why I was upset when I was told it's working while it clearly wasn't (in the iframe). Will IDB work completely in next version in iframes, or is there still something to be added to the docs?

Comment: It will work in sandboxed iframes in 43, yes.  Unless the user turns off third-party cookies, in which case it won't.  But it would also not work in non-sandboxed cross-origin iframes then, of course.